# firebreath dockable window in a web browser

Tags: browser-plugin, browser-extension, firebreath

I want to create a dockable window on a web browser using Firebreath. The plugin, when registered, should be invoked *by* the browser and displayed in some section *of* the browser. I am new to this, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with FireBreath; what you need is an extension (add-on), not a plugin.

See http://npapi.com/extensions

Comment: worth mentioning that if you create an extension you could potentially use a firebreath plugin to provide additional functionality. Many people have used FireBreath that way.